# Is this expression "Ich habe den ganzen Tag verbracht Deutsch zu lernen" Correct?

Tags: phrase, expression

Can anyone tell me please whether this sentence

> Ich habe den ganzen Tag verbracht Deutsch zu lernen

is correct or not, if it's not correct can you tell me the right structure with same meaning

Answer (score 8):

You are very close. You are just missing one word:

> Ich habe den ganzen Tag damit verbracht, Deutsch zu lernen.

The structure is "etwas mit etwas verbringen". Since you use an *erweiterter Infinitiv mit zu* for the prepositional phrase "mit etwas", you need to insert the *Verweiswort* (*Präpositionalpronom*) "damit" because a preposition cannot just be omitted. If the *erweiterter Infinitiv mit zu* refers to such a *Verweiswort*, the comma is mandatory.

Other such *Verweisworte* are *danach*, *darüber*, *davon*, *dafür*, *daran*, *dadurch* ... They all are build by putting *da(r)-*  in front of the preposition.

Comment: Is "den ganzen Tag" here in the accusative case because it's a temporal adverbial expression, as in (Wir waren den ganzen Tag unterwegs)...or because it is an accusative object to "verbringen"?

Comment: The latter ....

Comment: While Roland's answer is perfectly valid, you could also say „Ich habe den ganzen Tag mit Deutschlernen verbracht“.

Comment: Is Deutschlernen a word?